# How to reshape a numpy data table?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, formatting

I'm pretty new to python and I have a task to "reshape" some data in a .txt file. The simplified format of the original data looks like this:

```
A 1 x      
A 2 y      
A 3 z    
B 1 q    
B 2 w    
B 3 e   
 ...
```

What I need to get looks like this

```
  A B
1 x q
2 y w  
3 z e
 ...
```

The thing is, there are multiple .txt files I have to reshape and there's no fixed number of 1-2-3s per A-B-C, meaning A could go from 1 to 50, while B could go from 1 to 10 or 75.
I'm looking for an algorithm on how to do this, I've figured how to reach the data I need and discard the data I don't need, but I can't figure how to "reduce" the dimension of data.

What I've done so far is getting the necessary data in arrays and putting those arrays in a numpy array

`data = np.array([station, depth, temperature])`

Now I'm trying to fill a new 2d data array, with x and y axis being the number of different stations and depths: if the original data has `AAAABBCCDDDD`, then the new data array's x axis will contain `ABCD` (using `Counter().keys()`).

Comment: Maybe you could just show what you've tried, instead of describing?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I mean, I sure can, but it's mostly number and string extraction from the .txt file, I doubt it will help with reformatting...

Comment: look into pandas, the operation you want is called pivot

Comment: @ChristianSloper thank you, I've just found out about it. i'm very used to C so it's pretty new to me that other languages have the functions already installed.

Comment: What do you do, if for a number, B does not have a value? For example A has 4 values and B only 3, when you reach that forth element what happens with B, what do you place there?

Comment: @Countour-Integral leave it empty or place a 0/NaN, the missing number is either a temperature or salinity, so it has physical ramifications which will be removed or obvious when plotting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could parse everything, reading line by line, and store the values in a dictionary. Since each line looks something like `A 1 x`      , the general case is as follows

```
BIG_LETTER INDEX VALUE WHITESPACE
```

In the dictionary, you would have as `keys` the **BIG_LETTER**'s and as the `values` another dictionary that stores the index and the value, something like `{A : {1: 'q', 2: 'c'}}`. This can trivially be achieved.

```
replace_with_your_file_name = "./text.txt"
with open(replace_with_your_file_name, "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip().split(' ') # remove ending whitespace and split ''
    
        # Store in a dictionary the big letter and all its values
        # something like {A : {1: 'q', 2: 'c'}}
        if not line[0] in data: 
            data[line[0]] = {}
        data[line[0]][line[1]] = line[2] # data[ big_letter ][number] = char
```

Then, after that is finished you could use another for loop to sort the `keys` in the nested dictionary, so if it was `{'B' : { 5: 'a', 2:'c'  } }` it would become `{'B' : {2: 'c', 5: 'a'}}`. Also you can then easily extract for each big letter the `maxmium` number they have a value for, which solves the problem of non-fixed length. The highest `maxmium` number is saved for later.

```
# Sort the by the dictionary key
GLOBAL_MAX_NUMBER: int = 0 # the larget number among all big letters

for item in data:
    big_letter: dict = data[item]

    data[item] = dict(sorted(big_letter.items(),)) # Sorth according to the keys
    local_max_number = list(data[item])[-1] # The last element is the largest
    
    if local_max_number > GLOBAL_MAX_NUMBER:
        GLOBAL_MAX_NUMBER = local_max_number

iterations = GLOBAL_MAX_NUMBER # Improve readability
```

Now you can write the data in a new file in the format you wish

```
# Write them to a new file
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as file:
    # FORMAT: A B C D ... (BIG NUMBRES)
    # ----- 1 a b c d ... (INDEX AND VALUE FOR EACH BIG LETTTER IN THE FIRST ROW)

    # Write all the big letters in a row
    WHITESPACE: str = "  "
    file.write(WHITESPACE + " ".join(list(data)) + "\n") 
    
    # that `GLOBAL_MAX_NUMBER` we kept track off
    for i in range(iterations):
        current_number: int = i+1 # Current index
        file.write(f'{current_number} ')

        for big_letter in data: # A, B, C ...
            if current_number not in data[big_letter]:
                file.write("0 ") # in case this does not exist write 0
            else:
                file.write(f'{data[big_letter][current_number]} ') # write the value
        
        file.write("\n")
```

All of the above, combined would give the desired output

```
  A B
1 x q 
2 y w 
3 z e
```

Comment: Your effort is much obliged. I'm a bit dumb and figured the problem is much more complicated than it is, it can literally be done with pandas in 2 lines of code. However, I commend your effort and I'm sure it's going to help someone. Cheers.